# Pass dynamic value to Gravity Forms using PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

**SCENARIO:**
There is an events page which allows users to buy tickets for an event. Each event has a different ticket price, but they all use the same Gravity Form to process the payment through the Gravity Forms PayPal add-on.

**PROBLEM:**
How do you pass the price of an event from the events page to the Gravity Form for PayPal to process?

The user must **not** have access to change the price.

Comment: This means no _GET requests or editable fields for script kiddies to toy with if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the price via dynamic population is probably your best bet. Here is an article I wrote that sounds like it's spot on for your current scenario.

http://gravitywiz.com/dynamic-products-via-post-meta/